# My daughter and her golf team want to make golf tees to sell and raise funds for their season. Is this ok to do or must they seek out permission?

Tags: patent-infringement

Their plan is to make the tees and paint them in different designs. Then they are going to package them and sell online and in the neighborhood.  Is this ok to do?  I know there are several patents for golf tees and I don't wish for them to get into any trouble. Any advice?

Comment: Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.  Even if just another direction to look into for advice.  Thanks

Comment: Hi, Ask Patents is a website to ask about the patent process or to help find Prior Art on US Patent Applications and US Patents. Unfortunately, questions about copyright, trademark, and licensing are outside the scope of this site.  Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that since golf tees have been around for scores of years, that there aren't any patents on them, but in any case, you might not want to copy the look-and-feel of a tee, as it might be a problem on copyright grounds, but that's off-topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and that's kind of what I figure too, but want to be sure.  There are over 30 patents on golf tees in general that I can find.  Any advice on where I could find more info on it?

Comment: How old are these patents? If you find patents that have expired, then you can copy them and not have to worry about patent infringement.

Comment: The look of a tee can also be covered in a design patent as well as copyright and trademark, trade dress. It is very hard to imagine that the shape of a generic tee is protected at this point or that